# Issues with gpg revocation design

Tags: gnupg, private-key, public-key, trust

I am making my own gpg server (based on the MIT one). I noticed something weird in the GPG chain of trust.

1. I create my `VeryTrustedKey`. I push it to my gpg server. In my code, I force all users to have `full` trust for this key. It will be the `trusted introducer` for all users.
2. A user `User1` upload his key `key1` to my server. It is signed by `VeryTrustedKey` on day 1 of the upload.
3. On day 2, a user `User2` import this `key1` key. Because `User2` has a trust `full` on `VeryTrustedKey` he also has a trust `full` on `key1`.
4. On day 3, `User1` loses his private key. `VeryTrustedKey` revoke the signature it has with `key1`.

The issue is that on day 4, `User2` still fully trust `key1`, even after refreshing from the server (A refresh by command line using `gpg --recv-key` KEYID then gpg `--refresh-keys`)
Is that normal ? How can I make it that trust will go away on a `trust introducer` revokation.

Comment: `on day 4, User2 still fully trust key1, even after refreshing from the server` - How User2 refreshed from the server?  Which commands he used?

Comment: I did it a refresh by command line using `gpg --recv-key KEYID` then `gpg --refresh-keys` @ESkri